# How can i design a Model of a document contains more than one collection in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, retrofit

I am novice in mongodb.

I have a mongodb and i have a table / document(Ex: sampleTable).

I know how to retrieve data from this single table.

I used below code to retrieve data and working fine.

```
@Document(collection="sampleTable")
public class sampleMapping {
    private String id;
    private String strClassName;
public sampleMapping () {}

    public sampleMapping (String strClassName) {
        super();
        this.strClassName = strClassName;
    }

    public String getStrClassName() {
        return strClassName;
    }
    public void setStrClassName(String strClassName) {
        this.strClassName = strClassName;
    }
}
```

But now, i wanted to retrieve data from more than one table. How can i do that?
Say, i need to retrieve table1 and table2.
How can i update the above code to get data from multiple collections?

Comment: The getter and setter are irrelevant to the question, aren't they?

Comment: Thanks for responding. That is sample pseudo code. Unfortunately, i didnt get what mistake i have done in the above getter and setter methods.

Comment: If it does not add anything to the question, please remove it.